# No Internet from internal GSM modem, but only in Guest OS (KVM/Qemu)

Tags: networking, qemu, kvm, libvirt, lte

I have been trying to set up a virtual router on my laptop utilizing the LTE card (Sierra Wireless AirPrime EM7455) as its WAN interface.

To summarize my problem, the LTE card works in the host but I can not get internet when I've forwarded it to a guest VM.

## Hardware / Software info

- Laptop: Lenovo Yoga 370 20JJ running Debian 11.7 (minimal net install running i3)
- LTE modem card: Sierra Wireless AirPrime EM7455
- Virtualization: KVM/QEMU/libvirt + virsh

## On the host

Using ModemManager and without using NetworkManager (out of preference) I am able to connect using the following in the host:

```
mmcli -m 0 --enable
mmcli -m 0 --simple-connect="user=3,apn=data.tre.se,ip-type=ipv4"
```

Then manually configuring the network as follows:

```
ip link set wwan0 up
ip addr add [IP/PREFIX] dev wwan0
ip link set dev wwan0 arp off
ip link set dev wwan0 mtu [MTU]
ip route add default dev wwan0 metric 200
```

I am able to get a connection. Ping works. I can browse the internet, etc.

## In the guest

In the guest, I forward the LTE modem (which appears as a USB device) using `virsh attach-device`. I am unable to connect to the internet If I duplicate the above commands used on the host system. I get no responses for any packets, including pings to the gateway IP. Instead I get only TX and RX errors:

```
user@modem:~$ ip -c -s link show wwan0
3: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 66:24:85:3c:8e:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX:  bytes packets errors dropped  missed   mcast           
             0       0  20621       0       0       0 
    TX:  bytes packets errors dropped carrier collsns           
             0       0      9       0       0       0
```

But the weirdest thing to me is that *I am* able to:

#### 1. Get an IP from the APN through `mmcli`

Once I've run the `--simple-connect` command in the guest, there is a Bearer setup and the modem is listed as "connected". See the output below for the modem info and bearer info respectively:

```
$ sudo mmcli -m 0
  --------------------------------
  General  |                 path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
           |            device id: [REDACTED]
  --------------------------------
  Hardware |         manufacturer: Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
           |                model: Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
           |    firmware revision: SWI9X30C_02.33.03.00
           |       carrier config: default
           |         h/w revision: EM7455
           |            supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |              current: gsm-umts, lte
           |         equipment id: [REDACTED]
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.7/usb1/1-4
           |              drivers: cdc_mbim
           |               plugin: sierra
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm0
           |                ports: cdc-wdm0 (mbim), wwan0 (net)
  --------------------------------
  Status   |                 lock: sim-pin2
           |       unlock retries: sim-pin2 (3)
           |                state: connected
           |          power state: on
           |          access tech: lte
           |       signal quality: 74% (recent)
  --------------------------------
  Modes    |            supported: allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |              current: allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
  --------------------------------
  Bands    |            supported: utran-1, utran-3, utran-4, utran-5, utran-8, utran-2, 
           |                       eutran-1, eutran-2, eutran-3, eutran-4, eutran-5, eutran-7, eutran-8, 
           |                       eutran-12, eutran-13, eutran-20, eutran-25, eutran-26, eutran-41
           |              current: utran-1, utran-3, utran-4, utran-5, utran-8, utran-2, 
           |                       eutran-1, eutran-2, eutran-3, eutran-4, eutran-5, eutran-7, eutran-8, 
           |                       eutran-12, eutran-13, eutran-20, eutran-25, eutran-26, eutran-41
  --------------------------------
  IP       |            supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  --------------------------------
  3GPP     |                 imei: [REDACTED]
           |        enabled locks: fixed-dialing
           |          operator id: 24002
           |        operator name: hallon
           |         registration: home
           | packet service state: attached
  --------------------------------
  SIM      |     primary sim path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0
           |       sim slot paths: slot 1: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0 (active)
           |                       slot 2: none
  --------------------------------
  Bearer   |                paths: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/0
```

```
$ sudo mmcli -m 0 -b 0
  ------------------------------------
  General            |           path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/0
                     |           type: default
  ------------------------------------
  Status             |      connected: yes
                     |      suspended: no
                     |    multiplexed: no
                     |      interface: wwan0
                     |     ip timeout: 20
  ------------------------------------
  Properties         |            apn: data.tre.se
                     |        roaming: allowed
                     |        ip type: ipv4
                     |           user: 3
  ------------------------------------
  IPv4 configuration |         method: static
                     |        address: A.B.C.58
                     |         prefix: 30
                     |        gateway: A.B.C.57
                     |            dns: 80.251.201.178, 80.251.201.177
                     |            mtu: 1500
  ------------------------------------
  Statistics         |     start date: 2023-08-11T10:16:31Z
                     |       duration: 30
                     |   uplink-speed: 50000000
                     | downlink-speed: 300000000
                     |       attempts: 1
                     | total-duration: 30
```

(some info redacted)

#### 2. Even send SMS from the guest to my mobile through `mmcli`

This says to me that the problem isn't with the modem connecting to the cell tower, and more localized to my network configuration or something to do with how the hardware is forwarded to the VM. Possibly a firmware issue where that's concerned?

## Troubleshooting attempted

### Different version of ModemManager and Debian

I have tried on both Debian 11.7 and latest stable Debian (12.X) in the guest. These ship with different versions of ModemManager (1.14.12 and 1.20.4 respectively). There is no obvious difference and my host is running Debian 11.7 mmcli 1.14, though I did have to run the following command when faced with an error on Debian 12:

```
$ mmcli -m 0 -e
error: couldn't enable the modem: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Retry: Invalid transition'

$ sudo ln -sft /etc/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.d /usr/share/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.available.d/*
```

### NetworkManager integration with ModemManager

I have tried using the NetworkManager integration with ModemManager. I installed a fresh guest (Debian 12), installed NetworkManager and set up the GSM connection through that instead. As a result I get an IP, gateway, DNS servers etc and the connection is displayed as being "connected", but I still get only errors for RX/TX

## Firewalls

I have ensured that `nftables` is disabled. No other firewall exists on the system unless there is something about virsh and networking I don't know.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm new to ModemManager and related technology. I'm hoping there is some fatal and rudimentary networking mistake I have made.